# Return output of flatMap from Spring Reactive POST request

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am trying to build a POST request using Spring WebFlux reactive programming. Below is my handler code:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getDataPOST(ServerRequest request) {
    Mono<Request> requestBodyMono = request.bodyToMono(Request.class);
    Mono<ServerResponse> responseBodyMono =  requestBodyMono.flatMap(requestBodyObj -> {
        Mono<ServerResponse> response = someFunction(); //Returns Mono<ServerResponse>
        return response;
    });
    return responseBodyMono;
} 

public Mono<ServerResponse> someFunction() {
    //..Some processing..
    String body = "Some body after processing";
    return ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(body);
}
```

The code is getting compiled without errors but when I run and call the request, I get an empty response. This is because my `responseBodyMono` is not getting any data. After debugging, I found that the code inside the `flatMap` method is not getting executed (perhaps because it is async?). How can I get the response returned correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that `flatMap` will only run if the POST body has all the parameters which are being accessed from the request. I was sending an empty body and thus, the `flatMap` function wasn't being called and a simple 200 OK response was being returned. If you send incorrect/incomplete parameters, it gives a bad request response automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In reactive nothing happens until you subscribe. You need to chain async/sync functions using reactive operators like `flatMap`, `map`, etc. For example, in your case it would look like

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getDataPOST(ServerRequest request) {
    return request.bodyToMono(Request.class)
            .flatMap(requestBodyObj -> someFunction());
}

private Mono<ServerResponse> someFunction() {
    //..Some processing..
    String body = "Some body after processing";
    return ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(body);
}
```